# How to position below image with absolute layout in css?

Tags: html, css

I am struggling to put the text below the image with a profile like image button. How can I ensure my text is below the image and do overlap with the image? How to position the icon on the center of the image?

```
<div class="profile-img-container">
 <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png" 
    class="img-thumbnail img-circle img-responsive" />
 <i class="fa fa-upload fa-5x"></i>
 </div>
<input id='uploadfile' type ='file'>
<p>this text is actually hidden but it should be visible and appear right after the image.</p>
```

Please have a look at my code at: http://jsfiddle.net/aLsxcejn/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post all the code in your question using the Snippet feature, and not just a fiddle link. Also, why are you using `position: absolute`? Based on the code you did show, there is no reason to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add innecesary `position: absolute` in your rules, there is an option:

```js
$('.profile-img-container').click(function() {
  $('#uploadfile').click();
});
```

```css
#uploadfile {
  display: none;
}

.profile-img-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
}

.profile-img-container:hover img {
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 501;
}

.profile-img-container:hover img+i {
  display: block;
  z-index: 500;
}

.profile-img-container i {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="profile-img-container">
  <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/765-default-avatar.png" class="img-thumbnail img-circle img-responsive" />
  <i class="fa fa-upload fa-5x"></i>
</div>

<input id='uploadfile' type='file'>
<p>this text is actually hidden but it should be visible and appear right after the image.</p>
```

Comment: Why does the icon upload flicker when hove?

Comment: Because yo set `:hover` on img, Set it to parent. I update my answer

Comment: But why does when I click on the icon, it does not trigger the browse file? Its only on the image?

Comment: Change event to the container, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following to your p tag.

```
p{
  position : absolute;;
  top : 180px;
  z-index : -1;
}
```

**NOTE :**  Text came below the image you can heck here [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldskf76a/)

Comment: In reality I have more items under the image. But the text still appears behind the image.

Comment: No. under the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to append this code in your CSS:

```
.profile-img-container {
    position: absolute;
    width:20%;
    left: 520px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

take a look at this [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/waroakawa/cxtgejsr/1/)

But If you want to show the image under text.. try to add:

```
.profile-img-container {
    position: absolute;
    width:20%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```